# Is it possible to play audio that's behind basic authentication in Firefox?

Tags: html, html5-audio, basic-authentication

I'm trying to play an audio file that's on a WebDAV server which uses basic authentication. I'm using an `<audio>` element and `createMediaElementSource`.

I'm currently using the following, which works in Chrome, but not Firefox.

```
<audio src="http://username:password@webdav.server" crossorigin="use-credentials" />
```

Anyone know an alternative way, or a way to get this to work in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding an authorization header through a service worker.

Comment: Can you share how you did this. Thanks

Comment: @Tom Sure, you can do this by manipulating a `Request` in the service worker's `fetch` event. Example: https://github.com/icidasset/diffuse/blob/6837490c25ec5a534fffdeb3abc818dea9386665/src/Javascript/Workers/service.js#L104